# Is there a Bool or Flag you can use in QML to determine whether a phone is running the application?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, programming, ubuntu-sdk, qml

For example:

```
Text {
    text: isPhone ? "this application is running on a phone" : "this application is not running on a phone"
}
```

Comment: ofono seems to be able to give the type of supported radio (See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ofono/+bug/1346790) and the System Settings app should get the info. Ask on the mailing list (https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone)

Comment: Supported radio? Sorry you have me at a disadvantage; is this app just utilizing a flag that tells them which form factor is currently using the application?

Comment: I think the info comes from a plugin written in c++. I tried to explore this part of the code but I'm not really familiar with it. I guess that if somewhere we can detect if the device is a 2G/3G modem then we can set this kind of property in QML.

Comment: Ah ; I take it this is a roundabout way to detect the form factor. Although my question would be whether my laptop, which can also connect to 2g and 3g would also be interpreted as a modem in this case.

Comment: Heh; I'll ask the devs when they come online.